# KERNEL: Error: KERNEL_0160 Delta count overflow. RS trigger

Tags: vhdl

```
    clock_proc : process begin 
x1 <= '0';
wait for 8 ns ;
x1 <= '1';
wait for 8 ns ;
end process ;
reset_proc : process begin 
reset <= '0';
wait for 2 ns ;
reset <= '1';
wait ;
end process ;
test_proc : process begin 
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '0'; 
wait for 20 ns ;
x2 <= '1'; x3 <= '1'; x4 <= '0'; 
wait for 20 ns ;
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '0'; 
wait for 20 ns ;
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '1'; 
wait for 20 ns ;
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '0'; 
wait for 50 ns ;
x2 <= '1'; x3 <= '1'; x4 <= '0'; 
wait for 20 ns ;
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '1'; 
wait for 20 ns ;
end process ;
```

> KERNEL: Stopped at time 20 ns + 5000.
>
> KERNEL: Error: KERNEL_0160 Delta count overflow. Increase the
>   iteration limit using -i argument for asim or the matching entry in
>   simulation

Comment: The error must be elsewhere in your code; I see nothing wrong here. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The error happens because there is some code that is iterating without time passing - ie only delta cycles.   In particular, what happens in the code that you did not show us when, X2 = 1 , X3 = 1, and X4 = 0.   What Matt means is that if we (or you) were to run only the code above, the error would not happen.   Hence, show us a small code example that when you simulate it will exhibit the error.